# Komma nach mehreren Sätzen wörtlicher Rede + Konjunktionen wie und/oder?

Tags: conjunction, comma

Nach Wörtlicher Rede setzt man ja eigentlich ein Komma. Etwa:

"Ich gehe nach Hause", sagte Peter.

Aber vor "und" und "oder" setzt man ja in der Regel kein Komma. Etwa:

Er geht nach Hause, öffnet die Tür und isst dort etwas.

Wie ist es aber bei mehreren Wiedergaben von wörtlicher Rede, die mit "und" bzw. "oder" verbunden werden.Z. B.:

Über einen Baum sagen Menschen verschiedene Sachen, etwa: "Ein Baum ist groß", "Ein Baum hat Blätter"[,] und "Ein Baum ist schön".

Setzt man hier jetzt ein Komma?

Comment: Elemente von Aufzählungen (dein Beispiel ist eindeutig eine) trennt man mit Kommata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das Komma zwischen wörterlicher Rede und *sagte Peter* rührt laut amtlichem Regelwerk aus folgender Regel:

> § 93. Folgt nach dem angeführten Satz der Begleitsatz oder ein Teil von ihm, so setzt man nach dem abschließenden Anführungszeichen ein Komma.
> Ist der Begleitsatz in den angeführten Satz eingeschoben, so schließt man ihn mit paarigem Komma ein.

Dass vor dem *und* in *Er geht nach Hause, öffnet die Tür und isst dort etwas* kein Komma steht, folgt wiederum aus den Rechtschreibregeln:

> § 72. Sind die gleichrangigen Teilsätze, Wortgruppen oder Wörter durch
> *und, oder, beziehungsweise/bzw., sowie (= und), wie (= und), entweder ... oder, nicht ... noch, sowohl ... als (auch), sowohl ... wie
> (auch)* oder durch *weder ... noch* verbunden, so setzt man kein
> Komma.

Diese Regel ist einschlägig, weil es sich im Beispiel um gleichrangige Elemente handelt.

Daher lautet die Antwort auf die Frage: Vor dem *und* in *Über einen Baum sagen Menschen verschiedene Sachen, etwa: "Ein Baum ist groß", "Ein Baum hat Blätter" und "Ein Baum ist schön"* steht **kein** Komma. Dies ergibt sich aus § 72, während § 93 hier in Ermangelung eines Begleitsatzes nicht einschlägig ist.

<sub>Alle Zitate nach Rechtschreibrat, Amtliches Regelwerk, Fassung 2018, https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201 und https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6206.</sub>